# Identify which Identity Provider sent the response - OneLogin SAML Java

Tags: java, saml, saml-2.0

I have OneLogin's SAML plugin in Java. While trying to process the login response, the API requires the same settings used during the login request. However, I have multiple instances of my web server running, so the response could go to a different server than the request. If the response is not encrypted, I can use the `InResponseTo` attribute to track the settings between instances of the web server. But if the response is encrypted, there is no way for me to track the settings.

```
 InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_4fee3b046395c4e751011e97f8900b5273d56685"
```

How is it possible to identify the Identity Provider's configuration on receiving the response? Any help would be appreciated.

```java
Auth auth = new Auth(settings, request, response); 
// This settings object is needed to decrypt the response
auth.processResponse();
if (!auth.isAuthenticated()) {
   out.println("Not authenticated");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the whole SAML response is encrypted there is no way to find out the issuer. Otherwise the 'Issuer' element of the SAML response would tell you the entity ID of the SAML IdP.

Comment: In case of one Service Provider contacting multiple Identity Providers, how will the Service Provider know which Identity Provider sent the response if the entire response is encrypted?

Comment: Not at all, but actually from SAML point of view it does not have to care as it has a trust with all those IdPs. It does not matter which IdP sent the assertion about the authenticated subject.

Comment: Agreed. But different Identity providers have different encryption keys. So  how will the SP know with which key to decrypt unless it knows which IdP sent the response?

Comment: Actually the "whole SAML response" is not encrytpted. Ony the Assertion or/and the NameID and Attributes are encrypted. Please check SAML XSDs.

Comment: I tried OneLogin 's online Dev tools. If you provide them with a SAML Response and a key, they encrypt the entire response. If the response isn't fully encrypted and I'm able to get the entity ID or the InResponseTo attribute, it would solve my problem.

Comment: Then this is a proprietary feature of OneLogin, which is not compliant to SAML specification. Potentially you just did it wrong. As you can see from https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/examples/response there is only an ecrypted Assertion. In addition to this it's also possible to encrypted Attributes and or the NameID instead of the whole Assertion.

Comment: After searching through multiple forums, I have to agree with you The online encryption tool which OneLogin has provided is just a generic encryption tool. According to Saml schema, Issuer, EntityID and InResponseTo will not be encrypted so they can be used to decrypt the response.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when handling the response you need to be able to identify where the request came from?

I think you should be able to do this with RelayState. In their docs (at https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml) they how the `login()` method can take RelayState info:

> We can set a 'returnTo' url parameter to the login function and that will be converted as a 'RelayState' parameter

```
String targetUrl = 'https://example.com';
auth.login(returnTo=targetUrl)
```

Calling the parameter `returnTo` is misleading in my opinion because it's implying behavior that isn't there. It should have just been called "relayState."

When that comes back in the response, it's just an additional request parameter. In the docs, they show an example of using the RelayState value to route the response, but you can do anything you want with that information:

```
String relayState = request.getParameter("RelayState");
//do whatever you want based on this request parameter
```

Comment: Not exactly. The problem is that the response can be returned by any IDP. And each IDP has different encryption and signing keys. I will be able to get the response details including relay state only if I decrypt the message with the right key. And I need to find a way to track which IDP the request is going to without the use of session.

Comment: Ah ok, yes. I see the problem. Sorry incorrect info then!

Answer (score 0):

**Question**:
If the response is not encrypted, I can use the InResponseTo attribute to track the settings between instances of the web server.

But if the response is encrypted, there is no way for me to track the settings.

How is it possible to identify the Identity Provider's configuration on receiving the response?

And I need to find a way to track which IDP the request is going to without the use of session.

**Answer**:

(1) Each IdP needs to post the SAML response to AttributeConsumingService endpoint such as https://sp.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

(2) Different IdP should have different entityID.

(3) SAML 2 supports the encryption of assertions, NameIDs, and attributes.

(4) **Quote** "How is it possible to identify the Identity Provider's configuration on receiving the response?"

Whether IdP encrypts assertions, NameIDs, or/and attributes is determined by SP. Diffferent SAML SP may have different requirements, such as sign assertion or sign response or encrypt assertions, NameIDs, or/and attributes.

SAML IdP needs to provide the corresponding configuration to meet the requirement of SAML SP.
[Relying party/SP configuration of Shibboleth IdP at GitHub repository](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP/blob/master/shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/conf/relying-party.xml) provides a configuration example for selected SAML SPs.

SP uses the entityID of IdP to identify the Identity Provider's configuration on receiving the response if SP have different requirements for different IdPs.

(5) Multiple IdPs can send the response to the same ACS. Usually for each time SP login, only one IdP sends the SAML response to the ACS. Then SP uses its own private key to decrypt assertions, NameIDs, or attributes.

**Resolution**(Some commercial SAML SPs adopt this solution):

Create different AttributeConsumingService endpoints for different IdPs, that is,

https://your-sp.com/SAML2/POST/idp1

https://your-sp.com/SAML2/POST/idp2

https://your-sp.com/SAML2/POST/idp3

Then different IdP posts the SAML response to different AttributeConsumingService endpoints.

SP uses its own private key/cert to decrypt assertions, NameIDs, or attributes, and then tracks which IDP the request is going to without the use of session.

**Note that** SP needs to provide different SP metadata with different ACS URL to different IdPs.

Comment: There are cases when multiple IdPs can send the response to the same ACS. The ACS just needs to know which Idp has sent it. This can be done from the InResponseTo or Entity ID attributes. They are never encrypted. Only Assertions, NameID and Attributes can be encrypted.

Comment: Multiple IdPs can send the response to the same ACS. Usually for each time SP login, only one IdP sends the SAML response to the ACS. Then SP uses its own private key to decrypt assertions, NameIDs, or attributes. I have updated my answer.